# Conditionally load vue-router

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am setting up my router on my main vue instance like so:

**router.js:**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: []
});
```

**Main Vue instance:**

```
import router from '@/router';

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',

    router,

    // etc.
});
```

Now I am running this inside a PHP application where this Vue instance is set up everywhere since I use Vue components all over the place.

The router is something I only use for a couple of pages though. There are only certain PHP pages I want to be able to have the Vue Javascript router.

Even on PHP pages where the `router-view` is not even loaded the router still activates. This is visible by the fragment:

```
#/
```

How would I make sure that the router only initiate on certain PHP routes(so to speak)?

Comment: What php framework are you using?

Comment: @samayo custom PHP with some Symfony components.

Comment: so why don't you require the vue.js and only on those pages you want to include it?

Comment: Because these pages also use other components, so they need access to Vue but they do not always need access to the router.

Comment: Do you have an PHP array of your php routes where you don't want vue route to work?

Comment: Yes I could manage to get such an array. Or better yet an array of routes where I do want it to work.

Comment: Yeah, then parse it to json and pass it to the router.

Comment: Even if I pass the exact routes I want the vue-router will still be active for other pages where Vue is active.

Comment: Yes, it will be active but it won't do anything. Or detect the page first and pass a conditional false to router as `new VueRouter({routes: {}})` If there is a logic behind your routing scheme as in, if you don't want vue-router to ignore anything after `/category-foobar/` then you can use my answer to detect those page and ignore them. If you don't want your vue-router to even be loaded on php pages you don't need it to be, then maybe better do it from PHP require/include (or if you have asset management)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add global js variable to page. which will define that you need router or not. I assume that you can identify it by your php code.

so from php side you can write something like this based on condition true or flase;

```
// you can set this variable as per your need 
$needRouter = false;
```

then inside your html template

if its any template engine (for example we use twig) pass this variable in to template

```
<script>
    window.needRouter = {{ needRouter }};
</script>
```

or if you prefer to use core php

```
echo '<script>window.needRouter = ' . ($needRouter ? 'true' : 'false') . ';</script>';
```

> this will out put **<script>window.needRouter = true;</script>** or **<script>window.needRouter = false;</script>** based on condition.

now inside your main.js

```
import router from '@/router';

let vueOptions = {
    el: '#vue', 
    // we will not assign route here
    // etc.
};

if(window.needRouter) {
    // we will assign route here if window.needRoute is true
    vueOptions.router = router;
}

window.app = new Vue(vueOptions);
```

**if any confusion how you set js variable from php please comment.**

Comment: Works like a charm, the router will not even be instantiated on the pages where I don't need it. This allows for a proper solution to a Vue MPA (Multi Page Application). Now I just need to create different blocks of routes per page but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that :)